# Urn containing colored balls

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

We have an urn that has r red balls, w white balls and b blue balls. You have to pull out balls randomly without replacement. What is the probability that you remove all r balls before the first w?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blues are irrelevant. Imagine making a word of length $r+w$ using $r$ copies of R and $w$ of W. There are $\binom{r+w}{w}$ such words, all equally likely. And in only $1$ of them are all the R before all the W.